# Dynamic CSS class string in #linkTo helper (using ember.js version pre4)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sections">
  {{#each section in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "section" section}} {{ section.label }} {{/linkTo}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

and everything works fine.
My model object looks like this:

```
App.Section = DS.Model.extend({
 sectionDetail: DS.attr('number'),
 label: DS.attr('string'),
 cssClass: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and I would like to use the `"cssClass"` property inside the `"#linkTo"` helper. Now, how can it be done (syntactically)?

I tried this, but this obviously does not work, because using `{{section.cssClass}}` does not render the value of `section.cssClass` but the bare string `"{{section.cssClass}}"`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sections">
  {{#each section in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "section" section class="{{section.cssClass}}"}} {{ section.label }} {{/linkTo}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

I can't find a solution that does work, could someone point me in the right direction here, or it's simple not possible to achieve what I want to do? Should I construct the links differently?

Comment: I haven't personally used the `#linkTo` helper, but generally in views you should assign classes with `classNames`, or in this case `classNameBindings`. {{#linkTo "section" section classNameBindings="section.cssClass"}}

Comment: Thank you :) {{#linkTo "section" section classNameBindings="section.cssClass"}} did it!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling here, the solution is to use `classNamesBindings`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sections">
  {{#each section in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "section" section classNameBindings="section.cssClass"}} 
      {{section.label }}
    {{/linkTo}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep, I had this:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{bind-attr class=":toggle isLiked:toggleHighlight"}}>
```

And needed to do this, make it into an input helper, but couldn't figure how to close the element (novice):

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=isLiked}}
```

And so classNameBindings to the rescue:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=isLiked classNameBindings=":toggle isLiked:toggleHighlight"}}
```